# Downloading all files from an ftp directory beginning with a certain string

Tags: python, python-3.x

I would like to download all files from an ftp directory that begin with a certain letter or string (for example, the letter "G" or string "GL") I would know how to do this in glob, but not from an ftp directory.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure where you're getting stuck but you should be able to get a directory listing with [nlst](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ftplib.html#ftplib.FTP.nlst) and filter it however you want:

```
filelist = [fname for fname in f.nlst() if fname[:2] == 'GL']
```

Here's a full example:

```
import os.path, ftplib
f = ftplib.FTP('some.server.somewhere')
f.login('user', 'pass')
f.cwd('/some/dir')
output_dir = "/some/output/dir"
for fname in [i for i in f.nlst() if i[:2] == 'GL']:
    with open(os.path.join(output_dir, fname), "wb") as fout:
        f.retrbinary("RETR {0}".format(fname), fout.write)
```

Comment: Thanks. Is there a way I can specify a directory for the file to be stored?

Comment: You can open the file that you're storing the data in wherever you want -- open(os.path.join('/some/outputdir/', fname), 'wb').  I modified the example.